# Laravel Validation of <input type="text">: Why 'required|string'?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Correct me if I'm wrong:

If we have some form with `<input type="text" name='username'>` - when we enter something in that field (when it's **not empty**) and submit the form, that value will always be `string` on server-side (Laravel), right? `$request->username` will be a string?

I am asking this because I saw that in [Laravel's authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication) system there are validation rules like this:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
. . .
```

but I don't understand what's the point of having both `required` and `string` as validation rules? Isn't it enough to have only `required` because anything entered in that field will always be `string`?

Comment: they can be numeric,date,.. i guess

Answer (score 0):

The required means the input must be not be empty, but the string validation rule is just a way of ensuring that any value from the input field is a string value. Even if the input filed type is changed to something else i.e. date or numeric, only a string value is expected from the input

Comment: But even when the input field is *date* or *numeric* - the submitted value will *always* be a string (`$request->numeric_field` will be string).